# custom tcp over udp socket bind

Tags: c, sockets, tcp, bind

I am trying to make basic reliable connection over udp. I have defined the custom bind function which takes same kind of arguments as TCP bind but in my function during passing parameters I got the error message as below:

> bind() failed: Address family not supported by protocol
>   I have defined the r_bind function in one file and is accessed from next file. The function is as below:

```
int r_bind(int sockfd, struct sockaddr *addr,socklen_t addrlen){        
    return bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr*) &addr, addrlen);
}
typedef struct brp_socket{
    int sockfd;
    struct sockaddr_in brp_serveraddr;
    struct sockaddr_in brp_useraddr;
}brp_socket;
```

I have made call from user1.c file. The socket was created successfully but during binding I got the error. I have made the following function call.

```
  brp_socket socket_list[BRP_MAX_SOCKET];
  int socket_index = 0;
  int servSock; // Socket descriptor for server

  servSock = r_socket(AF_INET, SOCK_BRP, 0)  
  socket_list[socket_index].sockfd = servSock;  
  memset(&socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr, 0, sizeof(socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr)); // Zero out structure
  socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr.sin_family = AF_INET; // IPv4 address family
  socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY); // Any incoming interface
  socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr.sin_port = htons(servPort); // Local port

  if (r_bind(socket_list[socket_index].sockfd, (struct sockaddr*)&(socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr), sizeof(socket_list[socket_index].brp_serveraddr)) < 0)



#define SOCK_BRP 1     
 int r_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol){
        if(type == 1)
            {
            return socket(domain,SOCK_DGRAM,protocol);      
            }

    }
```

Here BRP_SOCK is custom made protocol type.
Can anyone suggest me where I made the mistake?

Comment: What is `SOCK_BRP`?  Don't you want to make that `SOCK_DGRAM` ?

Comment: SOCK_BRP is custom made protocol type. which in dept use the same SOCK_DRAM. I have use the following function for socket connection and defined the value in library file as                                            #define SOCK_BRP 1                                                                            int r_socket(int domain, int type, int protocol){
 if(type == 1)
  {
  return socket(domain,SOCK_DGRAM,protocol);  
  } 
}

Comment: Try `addr` instead of `(struct sockaddr*) &addr`. Note that `addr` is already a pointer to struct sockaddr. Taking the address of it again gives you a pointer to a pointer.

Comment: @  user3386109 Thank you the tips works perfectly but now i have stucked in others issues.